# I can not save my Excel file in Application.StartupPath()

Tags: c#

I can not save my Excel file in `Application.StartupPath()` when It's location is C Drive `C:\Program Files (x86)\DataSoft\Payroll etc`

Comment: Because Windows (with default settings) prevents you to save anything in Program Files folder. **Right** answer is not a workaround, just DO NOT DO IT. Use AppData folder, use User's documents folder. Anything else...

Answer (score 2):

Windows UAC blocks any writes to Program Files and other system folders by applications that lack the privileges. You can workaround that by running the application as Administrator (Right click the app icon -> Run as administrator) or by disabling UAC (which is a big security risk). 
So yes, consider saving your data into a different directory.